# Add a class when hyperlink is clicked on a different DIV

Tags: jquery, onclick

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgu46qzb/)

I'm trying to add a different class on the h1 when the hyperlink is clicked and if i click on the second one, have the first class clear and add a different one

Thanks guys, hope that's clear enough

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs hero-image-tabs">
    <li class="hero-img-1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="img/bg-img-hero-2.jpg">Hero 1</a></li>
    <li class="hero-img-2"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="img/bg-img-hero-8.jpg">Hero 2</a></li>

</ul>

<header class="hero-section py-5 ">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="display-4 text-white mt-4">Connecting Leaders. Inspiring Innovation.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. This is not a place for code requests.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple code based on li's position to insert the name of the class.
if this is not your needs , give me an other example.

```js
 var oldClass = $('div h1').attr("class");
 $("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
      var calssName =this.className;
     var position = $(this).index();
     
     if(position==0)
     {
       $('div h1').addClass(calssName).addClass("color-red");
       $('div h1').removeClass("color-green")
     }
     else if(position ==1){
       $('div h1').removeClass("color-red")
       $('div h1').addClass(calssName).addClass("color-green");
     }

})
```

```css
.color-red{color:red;}
.color-green{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="tabsnav" class="nav nav-tabs hero-image-tabs">
    <li class="hero-img-1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="img/bg-img-hero-2.jpg">Hero 1</a></li>
    <li class="hero-img-2"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="img/bg-img-hero-8.jpg">Hero 2</a></li>

</ul>

<header class="hero-section py-5 ">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="display-4 text-white mt-4">Connecting Leaders. Inspiring Innovation.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to change but you just need to add click events to each element and ensure that you remove the class from the other element that you didn't click within your event handler.

[Example CodePen](https://codepen.io/katrpilar/pen/KGYxOy)

```
$(".hero-img-1").click(
 function(){
  $(this).addClass("bolder");
  $(".hero-img-2").removeClass("bolder");
 }
);

$(".hero-img-2").click(
  function(){
    $(this).addClass("bolder");
    $(".hero-img-1").removeClass("bolder");
  }
);
```